# Runtime error with SIP-Viewer

Tags: java, sip, sip-server, genesys

I am trying to analyses Genesys SIP server logs with sip-viewer([Ref link](https://code.google.com/p/sip-viewer/)) , Unfortunately i am getting the below error while running.

**With command prompt,**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: SIP Server, Version: 8.1.
101.64 Compiled: Apr 17 2015 07:20:14 is not having the right format
        at javax.sip.viewer.parser.TextLogParser.parseMessageDetails(TextLogPars
er.java:66)
        at javax.sip.viewer.parser.TextLogParser.parseLogs(TextLogParser.java:37
)
        at javax.sip.viewer.SipTextViewer.display(SipTextViewer.java:73)
        at javax.sip.viewer.SipTextViewer.main(SipTextViewer.java:227)
```

**With Eclipse plugin,**
[image]

Anyone faced the same kind of issue and resolved it.. please guide me here

Comment: Can you share the code that causes this error?

Comment: @lenz i am just using the third party jar(sip-viewer) to analyses the log.. Ref - https://code.google.com/p/sip-viewer/downloads/list

Answer (score 0):

Check the sample file, your input file requires date format as follows:

```
[YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS.MSC]
```

Example:

```
[2011/01/13 08:55:56.109]
```

You need to convert your input file to sip-viewer [format](https://code.google.com/p/sip-viewer/source/browse/trunk/cli/examples/b2b-example.txt).

I worked a Java project to convert Mobicents, Cisco CTX and others to this format, it may help: 
https://github.com/spicyramen/ctx-log-parser

Comment: Thanks Spicyramen , But unfortunately i am unable to opened Genesys SIP server log with this tool.. it shows  "unknown log detected" . Could you please let me know about this..

Comment: Yes... you need to convert your Genesis file to the right format